# How to code grammar or lexer rule to describe JSP/EL identifier or string literal in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

How to code grammar or lexer rule to describe JSP/EL identifier or string literal in ANTLR? Remember, that JSP/EL is Unicode and you cannot list all possible symbols in a rule. Also remember, that strings can contain EL expressions, which may be complex, so lexer is insufficient to describe them, parser is required, while ANTLR parser is unable to match character classes or any character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the new "Lexical Modes":

> ### *Lexical Modes*
>
> *Modes allow you to group lexical rules by context, such as inside and outside of XML tags. It’s like having multiple sublexers, one for context. The lexer can only return tokens matched by entering a rule in the current mode. Lexers start out in the so-called default mode. All rules are considered to be within the default mode unless you specify a mode command. Modes are not allowed within combined grammars, just lexer grammars.*
>
> -- http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules

Comment: Oh no! Why not just remove lexer and let everything done by parser? Anyway thanks.

Comment: @SuzanCioc, that is not how ANTLR works. What you're looking for is a [PEG](http://bford.info/packrat/), in that case. I've heard good things about [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki).

Comment: PEG looks to be a concept. Are there any tools, like ANTLR, which utilize PEG? ANTLR is listed as PEG aware on your page.

Comment: I provided a link in my previous comment. And no, ANTLR is not really PEG (there *is* a strict separation between the lexer and parser).